# Why can't I apply subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^3$ on real projective plane

Tags: general-topology, projective-space

In Crossley's Essential topology, the line about $\mathbb{R}P^2$ - ***It is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, since the elements of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ are not points in $\mathbb{R}^3$
but subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$***

I am not getting the point once it is said $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ but elements of it are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^3$, what does it mean?

Basically, I am asking why can't I apply the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^3$? Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Your title is screaming but doesn't inform the reader what your question is about with any precision. I recommend you edit it

Comment: Can you give an example of a point in $\mathbb{R}P^2$?

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb RP^2$ is defined as a quotient space. The canonical construction of a quotient space is to let its elements be *equivalence classes*. In this case, these equivalence classes are actually sets of elements of $\Bbb R^3$, specifically, the point $[x]\in\Bbb RP^2$ is the set of all $y\in\Bbb R^3$ with $y=\lambda x$ for some nonzero $\lambda\in\Bbb R$.

You can't "apply the subspace topology" because there is no natural way to view $\Bbb RP^2$ as a sub*set* of $\Bbb R^3$ and its topology is the *quotient* topology, not the *subspace* topology. Perhaps there is a fancy embedding $\Bbb RP^2\hookrightarrow\Bbb R^3$, perhaps not - I wouldn't know. But thinking of it as a subspace (from a subset) is not right.

Answer (score 1):

Each element of the set $X = \{\{A,B\},\{B,C\},\{A,C\}\}$ is a subset of the set $\{A,B,C\}$, but $X$ itself is not a subset of $\{A,B,C\}$.

Similarly, each element of the set $\mathbb RP^2$ is a subset of the set $\mathbb R^3$, but $\mathbb RP^2$ itself is not a subset of $\mathbb R^3$. And to apply the subspace topology, you are required to start with a subset of $\mathbb R^3$.